# PostgreSQL problems running query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am having problems with the syntax on the below line. I can't seem to pinpoint what the issue is. I am using PostgreSQL, and am rewriting queries used from MySQL. I keep getting a syntax error.

```
sum(CASE WHEN(date(a.date_added) between ('{{2018-10-04}}', 
CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '14 DAY') and '{{2018-10-04}}',b.quantity,0)) THEN Sales14 END
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your syntax error?

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results can help.

Comment: This is supposed to pull the past 14 days of sales and summarize them according to part name.

Comment: This is the error notice Error running query: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 2: sum(CASE WHEN((date_added '2018-10-10'::date - cast ('14 DAY... ^

Comment: `{{2018-10-04}}` is not a valid constant for a date value.

Comment: If you want a conditional aggregate, using the [`filter()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`THEN Sales14 END` should be inside the parentheses

```
sum(CASE WHEN(date(a.date_added) between ('{{2018-10-04}}', 
    CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '14 DAY') and '{{2018-10-04}}',b.quantity,0) THEN Sales14 END)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is getting me closer to what I'm looking for, much appreciated.